# Android append file can't pass unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am trying to use android append on a txt file. The `append` method can't get passed the unit test.

example:

I tried to append "123456" twice to get "123456123456", but i got the error:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: expected:<123456[]> but was:<123456[123456]>
```

My question is what's the meaning of `<> []` in `<123456[]>` and `<123456[123456]>`?

My test method is as below, i can get passed the first `assertEqual`

```
 public void appendFileCorrect() throws Exception {
            String contentToWrite = "123456";
            Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
            FileManager manager = new FileManager("jim11.txt");
            manager.append(contentToWrite);
            String file = manager.readFromFile(appContext);
            assertEquals(file, contentToWrite);
            manager.append(contentToWrite);
            String appendFile = manager.readFromFile(appContext);
            assertEquals(appendFile, contentToWrite+contentToWrite);
        }
```

The method to **append** to the end of the file:

```
public String append(String content) throws IOException {

        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(content);
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```

The method to **read**

```
   public String readFromFile(Context context) throws IOException {

        String ret = "";
        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput(fileName);
            if (inputStream != null) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String receiveString = "";
                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
                ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Also my Android device has no SD card, any way i can write to a public place i can read the file directly? Right now the path is like "`data/data/files/..`"

Comment: the android device might have an emulated SD card, called `External storage`. You can read-write files there. What is your android device? Which version of Android at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
```

to

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
```

The second parameter means append or not.

Another way for append is:

`outputStream = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_APPEND);`

**Context.MODE_APPEND** mode will check file exist or not. If not then create the file and append on the end.